# Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 Favicon Generated on PNG format TEST

Tags: html, png, favicon, ico

I have done a favicon.ico for a quick client request, redone my cache but in my firefox it seems to show a blank favicon in the navbar, not sure if its my machine or not as tried on a offline native browser and get the same result however amazingly IE on my local seems to show as expected!

I done a 16x16 favicon based on PNG format to withhold the PNG quality of transparency but as i said above on firefox locally it shows nothing - can onlyone with firefox 2+ 3.x to latest 3.6 run a test for me to see if that can see the rugby ball favicon i have created as want to make sure its working off local before i do their other sites favicons! the site is ramrugby[dot]co[dot]uk

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comes up blank here. Photoshop won't read it as `.png` or as `.ico`

Answer (score 1):

It comes up blank for me.

There is no need to create an .ico file in .png format to retain transparency. ICO will already retain transparency.

The best way to create a proper .ico is to download the .ico photoshop plugin, which adds an additional ".ico" image format to your Photoshop "Save As" image format list.

The plugin is free, and you can get it here:

http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html

Download that, put it in your Photoshop > Plugins > File Formats folder, and save, then restart Photoshop and you can create icos.

Comment: that is what i done,i used the photoshop plugin and upon saving gives you 2 formats to save as - i will try again doing normal rather than PNG